# How to display panels region title?

Tags: 7, panels

How can I say Panels to show region title while rendering the page?

I have a panel region containing 4 node previews and I want to print a title before them. It would be like a "wrapping section" in my home page.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a template for your panel and add whatever div or wrapper you need there, by wrapping it around the content div. This post is a great resource:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1678810

In brief, for panel panes, your template file should be named:
panels-pane--[pane type]--[pane subtype].tpl.php

This post also shows you how to find your panel's machine name.

If you aren't familiar with templates, this is also a great resource:
https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme

Comment: As my need was a title for the region and not for a single pane (I have a region with multiple node teasers in it), I started from your idea and I created a custom pane as ctools plugin with a configurable string as parameter. In this way I can place a region title mostly everywhere.

Comment: nice! feel free to share your final solution code for others to enjoy :)